# To call a function in dart when there is an incoming call

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

how to call a dart function when we get an incoming call?
is it possible to do so, If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a native plugin for each platform to access platform specific apis.

I would suggest to search for existing [pub packages](https://pub.dev/packages?q=incoming+call). For example `incoming_call_event` looks promising.

```dart
    streamSubscription = incomingCallEvent.listen((IncomingCallEvent event) {
      print('Call is Incoming or Connected' + event.stateC);
      //event.stateC has values "true" or "false"
    });
```

as from https://github.com/syahrizalakbar/PhoneCallState